# IE 11 - onbeforeunload event calling twice

Tags: extjs, internet-explorer-11, onbeforeunload

I am using extjs. i have written code to provide warning message before redirecting other page. Warning message looks like below image

[image]

after clicking on "leave this page", same popup comes again. then after clicking on "leave this page". Here is code below:

```
Ext.EventManager.on(window, 'beforeunload', warnOnExit, this);// This has on document load.

//function definition
function warnOnExit(e) {

if (!bSkipChangesCheck)
  {
      e.browserEvent.returnValue = LY.Global.Misc.g_strWarnOnExit;
  }


}
```

To fix this I have change "warnonexit" function as below

```
 function warnOnExit(e) {
            if (!bSkipChangesCheck)
            {
              e.browserEvent.returnValue =LY.Global.Misc.g_strWarnOnExit;

              disableCheck();
            }
   }


function disableCheck() {
    bSkipChangesCheck = true;
    setTimeout("enableCheck()", "20");
}

function enableCheck() {
   bSkipChangesCheck = false;
}
```

This works for me.But the solution was not accepted by higher tech persons.

i want answers of below questions.

1. Is timeout is only solution of this? If there are any other solutions , Please provide me
2. Is this the actual bug on IE11?

Need help badly!!